# WebAPI .NET Core 3 basic authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, basic-authentication

I need to add a Basic Authentication to a set of API.

DISCLAIMER: *The APIs are inside an intranet and contains public data. They can be consumed from external users only through an API gateway where strong authentication and authorization are implemented. This Basic Authentication is needed only to avoid that internal development team calls directly this service. User and password are not the real one.*

I've used the package ZNetCS.AspNetCore.Authentication.Basic, version 4.0.0

This is my startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddAuthentication(BasicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddBasicAuthentication(
              options =>
              {
                  options.Realm = "My Application";
                  options.Events = new BasicAuthenticationEvents
                  {
                      OnValidatePrincipal = context =>
                      {
                          if ((context.UserName.ToLower() == "gateway0107") 
                                     && (context.Password == "jir6STt6437yMAQpl"))
                          {
                              var claims = new List<Claim>{
                                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,
                                                        context.UserName,
                                                        context.Options.ClaimsIssuer)
                                };

                              var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                                new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(
                                  claims,
                                  BasicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)),
                                new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties(),
                                BasicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

                              return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
                          }

                          return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Authentication failed."));
                      }
                  };
              });

        services.AddMvcCore();
        services.AddApiVersioning(
                            options =>
                            {
                                options.ReportApiVersions = true;
                            });
        services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(
            options =>
            {
                options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
                options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
            });
        services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>, ConfigureSwaggerOptions>();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(
            options =>
            {
                options.OperationFilter<SwaggerDefaultValues>();
                options.IncludeXmlComments(XmlCommentsFilePath);
            });

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: "AllowAllOrigins",
                              builder =>
                              {
                                  builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                              });
        });

        services.AddControllers(options =>
        {
            options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new SuppressChildValidationMetadataProvider(typeof(Point)));
            options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new SuppressChildValidationMetadataProvider(typeof(Coordinate)));
            options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new SuppressChildValidationMetadataProvider(typeof(LineString)));
            options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new SuppressChildValidationMetadataProvider(typeof(MultiLineString)));
        }).AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            foreach (var converter in NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJsonSerializer.Create(new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(), 4326)).Converters)
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(converter);
            }
        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
    {
        app.UseForwardedHeaders();
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
             Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "swagger-ui")),
            RequestPath = "/swagger-ui"
        });

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(
            options =>
            {
                // build a swagger endpoint for each discovered API version
                foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
                {
                    options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
                }
            });

    }
    static string XmlCommentsFilePath
    {
        get
        {
            var basePath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
            var fileName = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name + ".xml";
            return Path.Combine(basePath, fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

But testing in Postman and from SwaggerUI I get always 410 Unauthorized.
Setting a breakpoint inside the OnValidatePrincipal, it never gets hit.

Should I have to add something else?

Comment: Please, do not post sensitive data, like passwords

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Please read the post